# Explaining C code for tokenizer a string

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm newbie in C and I have a code but I don't understand part of it.

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t count;
    char** strings;
} Tokens;

Tokens Tokenize(char* String, char Split)
{
    Tokens t;
    t.count = 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; String[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        if (String[i] == Split)
            t.count++;
    }

    t.strings =(char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)* t.count);

    if (t.count > 0)
        t.strings[0] = String;

    for (size_t i = 0, j = 1; String[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        if (String[i] == Split)
        {
            t.strings[j] = &String[i + 1];
            String[i] = 0;
            j++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

The part that I don't understand is how a pointer to pointer char can tokenize the string part, especially that line t.strings[j] = &String[i + 1];

If someone can please make a visualization of the process I would be grateful. 
Thanks

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your code. There you have your "visualization". "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]." If it works, this is OT anyway, we are not code-explanation site - sorry.

Comment: @Olaf "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") ...." - Are you kidding me? as far as I can tell you he ISN'T seeking for debugging help and this code probably works. From when we aren't code-explanation site?? This is why SO is there.. to explain things to people.

Comment: @Quest  Thanks! so much for your comment

Comment: There is no clear problem statement and not what he expects the code to do. There is also no sign of research by OP to find out himself, or a **specific** question. For code review there is another site on stack exchange. And no, I'm not kidding - especially not **you** - why should I? You are not even affected.

Comment: @Olaf I've done a bit of research and I found out those questions are not allowed IF there is no specific problem. Otherwise those should be marked as Too broad. Sorry, my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> especially that line t.strings[j] = &String[i + 1];

In that line, `String[i]` is the delimiter char (`Split`) found, so `String[i + 1]` is the char at the beginning of the next token string.  The *address* of that char (`&String[i + 1]`), then, is the string pointer/address of the next token string.

`t.strings[]` is just a collection (array) of the string pointers to be found in `String`.

Comment: yes but how &String[i + 1], tokenized the string? if it points to the next token, what happend to the previous string before that token ? how it's saved so that it's now considered as a token? Can you put an image please ?

Comment: `String` is an address of a bunch of chars.  Let's use "abcXdefXanotherXtoken", where 'X' is the split char.  As the loop progresses, those characters become "abc_defXanotherXtoken" (where '_' represents the null I can't print), then "abc_def_anotherXtoken", and finally "abc_def_another_token".  The purpose of the `t.string[]` array is to make note of where to find the 'd' in "def", the 'a' in "another", and the 't' in "token".  Those addresses are string pointers.

Comment: The token strings stay in memory right where they started.  The nulls that replace the Split also happen to serve now as null terminating characters for the token strings.

Comment: so t_string[0] points to abc_ and t_string[1] points to def_ and so on ? can you put an image of t_string pointer please ?

Comment: Yes, you have those pointers correct.  I'd like to post an image for you, but I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: In my debugger, t_strings[0] points to def_X not to abc_. The image is just how the t_string points to

Comment: Ah, well, now you have a specific problem.  Welcome to StackOverflow!  :-)  Looking at the code posted, this seems impossible.  I believe you, though.  You may want to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example (MCVE) and post a fresh question.  It's a good one.

Comment: sorry it points to  def_XanotherXToken, at the next iteration it points to anotherXtoken, next iteration to points to token

Comment: @donjuedo: there is a symbol for NUL in Unicode at U+2400: ␀

Comment: Please post a final comment here, linking to your new question.  (That way, I can't miss it -- SO will notify me).  When I get home from work, I can copy your MCVE and see if I can reproduce the changing t.strings[0].

Comment: @ninjalj, Very cool!  How can I put that in comments?  (sorry, I'm a noob at formatting)

Comment: @donjuedo the final comment is: t_strings[0] points to defXanotherXtoken, t_strings[1] points to anotherXtoken, t_strings[2] points to token

Comment: @donjuedo: I just copy-pasted it from a character map application.

Comment: @donjuedo I made a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594674/debugger-shows-wrong-value-to-pointer