# Debugger shows wrong value to pointer

Tags: c, debugging

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <list>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <limits>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <bitset>
#include <numeric>
#include<fstream>



using namespace std;

char str[] = "this.is.a.test";
char str2[] = "this.is.another.test";

typedef struct
{
    size_t count;
    char** strings;
} Tokens;

Tokens Tokenize(char* String, char Split)
{
    Tokens t;
    t.count = 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; String[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        if (String[i] == Split)
            t.count++;
    }

    t.strings =(char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)* t.count);

    if (t.count > 0)
        t.strings[0] = String;

    for (size_t i = 0, j = 1; String[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        if (String[i] == Split)
        {
            t.strings[j] = &String[i + 1];
            String[i] = 0;
            j++;

        }
    }


    return t;
}

int main(void)
{
    Tokens t = Tokenize(str, '.');
    printf("number of strings: %i\n---\n", t.count);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < t.count; i++)
    {
        printf("%i: %s\n", i, t.strings[i]);
    }
    free(t.strings);

}
```

The problem is when I debug the code and especially that line  `t.strings[j] = &String[i + 1];`

In a test case of this.is.a.test

At the first found dot . , it should points to this, but in the debugger it shows the following picture.
[image]
    enter code here

Comment: Please don't cast `malloc()`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh If I don't cast, it shows that error Error 1 error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char **' c:\users\ahmed saleh\desktop\testalgo\testalgo\main.cpp 45 1 testalgo

Comment: Do not post screenshots! Copy/paste the text instead.

Comment: Then don't use a C++ compiler to compile C code.

Comment: Didn't you ask the about the same subject about an hour ago?

Comment: I asked him to post this, as it is a new problem on the same code.

Comment: are you aware you're incrementing `i` __twice__?

Comment: A complete, minimal example would be helpful, including `main()` and the parameters passed.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The second increment is a problem if the original `String` ends with a `Split` char.  Work is needed for that case.

Comment: @donjuedo I have posted the full code

Comment: `using namespace std;` Isn't this C++?

Comment: It looks like C to me, except for the namespace.  That `using` seems unused.

Comment: @WeatherVane: according to the libs? Yes. To the code? Well...

Comment: C does not have namespace

Comment: is there a problem to compile C code using C++ compiler ? there is nothing much C here except using malloc instead of new. But that doesn't interpret the behavior I'm getting.

Comment: C is not C++. Both are different languages. You should otherwise add Java and, Rust and Go tags.

Comment: @donjuedo what should t_strings[j] points to ?

Comment: " there is nothing much C here ..." The opposite is actually true. Aprat from the `namespace` and the plethora of libs. Get the tag and the code right and use the correct compiler! And replace the screenshot.

Comment: If you have to cast the value from `malloc` to prevent compiler error, I would suggest there is something wrong with what you are doing. So rather than accuse the debugger of telling you "wrong value to pointer" I would review the way *you* use them.

Comment: @WeatherVane: He has to if compiling C code as C++. There is too much confusion here.

Comment: @andre, `j` skipped 0, so first `t.string[j]` points to "is" (`j==1`).  Next, `t.string[j]` points to "a" (j==2), and so on.

Comment: @donjuedo can you show a picture of your debugger where t_strings[j] points to anything so that I can believe ?

Comment: @andre, I will try when I get home (~2 hours).  Your image is blocked from me here, behind the corporate firewall.

Comment: What is supposed error?  It looks to me like t.string[j] is pointing to the correct thing (the first letter past the first separator).   What am I missing?

Comment: @andre, yes, Russ is right.  The debugger shows the value correctly.  j == 1 there, so the string starting at "is" would be exactly right.  `t.strings[0]` still points to "this", although it is not currently shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the debugger shows is correct at line 55. The assignment has been made, so `t.strings[j]` points after the dot.

Note that in `Tokenize` you allocate `Tokens t;` on the stack and later return this `t`. That is bad (very bad!). Because `t` is on the stack, it will be overwritten by the call to `printf`.

(And although most is C, formally it is C++ as in C you cannot declare a variable in the `for` initialization, as in `for (size_t i = 0;`)

Comment: If It points after the dot, how it stores the tokenized strings before the dot ?

Comment: Your statement of `t.string[0]=String` sets the first token to the beginning of the string.   But you know that because you wrote the code, right?

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie:  returning `t` should be fine.   It'll be returned by value, and the internal pointer is pointing to memory that was malloc()ed and the pointer list that was allocated points to memory that was passed into `Tokenize()`.   Nothing is pointing to anything on the stack.

Comment: @andre, you do realize there is no copying going to store the tokenized strings, right?  Only the address is saved in the array, and the test text stays put, right where it started -- it never moves.

Comment: @Russ-Schulz, I see...actually I am (was/forgot/..) not aware of C being able to return anything larger than an int/pointer as (at least in MS C) the funtion return is always in the `ax` register, so how can a struct be returned in the ax register (unless the compiler immediately executes a `memcpy` operation). Thanks.